# HTML onClick doesn't work with Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-phone-8.1

I have an web app which is working phine on the simulator,android and ios, but on windows phone one onclick event does not work. This is my HTML code:

```
   <ul id ="triggerresolutionbg" class="table-view">
        <li class="table-view-cell media">
        <element>
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-left">
                <span class="icon icon-left-nav" id ="triggerLeft" onClick = "triggerText(this.id)" ></span>
            </button>
            </element>

            <button class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-right">
                <span class="icon icon-right-nav" id ="triggerRight" onClick = "triggerText(this.id)"></span>
            </button>
            <element>
                <center id ="triggerText">After I...</center>
            </element>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I´m using Ratchet,Bootstrap and JQuery.

Why the onclick methods on Windows Phone does not work ?

Comment: Incidentally, It's `onclick` not `onClick`. Although the browser should normalize.

Comment: try starting with `onclick="alert('test')"`

Comment: That was I try which way is working but that has no effect

Comment: I tried with a normal alert that does not work

Comment: last thought.. something strange with the css perhaps?  move the onclick to one of the parent containers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 spec for button](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-button-element) putting interactive content inside a button element is invalid.

> Content model:
>
> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

So you should not expect event listeners to work on elements inside a button. Some browser violate the spec and permit this, but others do not. Try attaching the `onclick` handler to the `button` element itself.

Since you are using `this.id`, I would recommend restructuring your HTML in the process, but something like this should work.

```
<button class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-left" onclick="triggerText(this.firstElementChild.id)">
    <span class="icon icon-left-nav" id="triggerLeft"></span>
</button>
```